# Angular2 enable/disable formcontrol on http response not working

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have formcontrol, when i provide [disable]="xyz" where xyz is variable in component assign from http response, angular2 give following warning.

It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
      when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
      you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

```
  Example: 
  form = new FormGroup({
    first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
    last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
  });
```

So i tried disable using following but not working

`this.form = this.fb.group({'type': [{ value: '', disabled: this.xyz },[Validators.required]]});`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
yourHttpFunction(){
 if(controlShouldBeDisabled){
  this.form.controls['first'].disable()
 }

}
```

Comment: Its working, but is there a solution with variable instead of calling `.disable()` explicitly.